# Rigging or Texture Painting, Which one should be made first? (Regarding Vertex Groups)

Tags: vertex-groups

there are many information about this subject but I couldn't find the specific answer to my question.

so, my goal is to use my model in UE4,

and as you know, in Blender, both for rigging and texture painting (outside of blender, in this case) you have to create vertex groups and assign them to required parts of the mesh; for rigging, one vertex group for the trigger, one for the hammer, etc. And for texture painting, there is no need for 2 separate vertex groups for trigger and hammer since both of those are metals.

Let's say, I exported the model to a painter software and came back into Blender; is it ok for me to delete previous vertex groups and create new ones for rigging?

I hope I made myself clear and thank you for reading.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion (meaning, not an ideal question for SE.)  There are reasons to prefer one or the other, and you can iterate: texture a little bit, rig a bit, texture a bit.  VGs are not typically involved in any texturing tasks; you certainly do not need to create+assign for texture painting.

Comment: @Nathan I am making texture painting in Quixel Mixer and in it,  in order to assign different materials to different parts of the gun, I am separating those parts in Blender with vertex groups. I don't know if there is any other way to do this.